# What does the blue I icon in SharePoint Designer 2007 mean?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

What does the blue I icon next to my custom display form mean?

[image: Designer screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page has been customized (un-ghosted) and has been disconnected from the master page. Any changes to the master page will not apply to that page.

This happens when you edit the page in advanced mode and change stuff other than web parts, for example create additional web part zones (or many other conceivable things).

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406685%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for details. The article is about WSS 3.0 but applies to MOSS 2007 as well.

[Edit:] corrected ghosted to un-ghosted as Per suggested.

Comment: A few corrections: (ghosted) should be (unghosted) and "master page" should be "file in the file system".

Comment: Thanks @PerJakobsen. I find the terminology mighty confusing.   Seems I'm not the only one. Here is an interesting [write-up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2007/11/03/sharepoint-terms-ghosted-unghosted-and-reghosted.aspx) that I should probably print out and put under my pillow.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can work out what I did to make it unghosted? As you can see I have custom new and edit forms and they are still ghosted